# Silverlight: Reference the same element multiple times without redundancy?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, dry

I'm building a Silverlight Windows Phone 7 app. I have the following element:

```
<TextBox x:Name="DownloadFailed"
         Text="MySite.com could not be reached at this time. Do you have a network connection? &#xd;&#xa;&#xd;&#xa;Try again in a few minutes." 
         BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}" 
         Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" Margin="56,8,8,-8" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

How can I define this once and add it to multiple pages in my app?

I could make a user control, but that seems like overkill for such a single element with a few properties.

Could I use the `StaticResource` dictionary somehow? Or is that just for properties?

The reason I'm doing this is because I have content on a number of different pages that the app attempts to load from a web service, but may fail. Is there a conventional design pattern / encapsulation for such a control/content?

Answer (score 0):

One way I have implemented this requirement in my apps to define this -

```
public static void ShowMessage(string message)
{
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show(message));
}
```

in a static `Helper` class. I then use it as -

```
Helper.ShowMessage("Error Loading Data from remote service. Please try again later.");
```

You may consider building a control that wraps the `TextBlock` (Your sample code uses `TextBox`, to display static text, you can use `TextBlock`) and invoke the control using the method above.

HTH, indyfromoz